# Error with My code to get date in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get sum of three  values  (EndDay + StartDay + months) so I need your help to correct my code .
I wrote this code once I run it I got 3 errors which is

> 1- Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'int' for 
>   float EndDate = (TO_DATE / EndDay);
>
> 2- CS0103  ASP.net The name does not exist in the current context in line 
>    int Date = EndDay + StartDay + months;

```
public float GetMonths(DateTime FROM_DATE, DateTime TO_DATE)
        {
            if (FROM_DATE > TO_DATE)
            {
                throw new Exception("Start Date is greater than the End Date");
            }

            int NumberOfMonths = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(FROM_DATE.Year, FROM_DATE.Month);
            if (FROM_DATE.Day != 1){

                float StartDay = (NumberOfMonths - FROM_DATE.Day) / NumberOfMonths;
            }
            else
            {
                float StartDay = 1;
            }

            float months = ((TO_DATE.Year * 12) + TO_DATE.Month) - ((FROM_DATE.Year * 12) + FROM_DATE.Month);
            int EndDay = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(TO_DATE.Year, TO_DATE.Month);
            if (TO_DATE.Day!= System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(TO_DATE.Year, TO_DATE.Month))
            {

                float EndDate = (TO_DATE / EndDay);
            }
            else
            {
                float EndDate = 1;
            }

            int Date = EndDay + StartDay + months;
            return Date;
        }
```

Comment: What is the function trying to do? What is the float returned suppose to be - number of days?

Comment: no it should return number of months

Comment: number of months what? Between the two dates? Partial, if there's 1 months and 4 days between the two dates? How would you handle which month the fraction comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is much simpler succient algorithim to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do - which is unclear - what is the `float` you return suppose to be of?

Generally if you want get the period of time between two `DateTime`'s simply find the difference:

```
TimeSpan diff = toDateTime - fromDateTime; // NOTE: the result is a `TimeSpan` type
```

Your immediate problems are:

```
float StartDay = (NumberOfMonths - FROM_DATE.Day) / NumberOfMonths;
```

Lets see what data types we are using:
NumberOfMonths is an `int`
FROM_DATE.Day is an `int`
NumberOfMonths is an `int`

What do we get if we divide an `int` by an `int`?

We get an `int`! If you want a `float` change at least one of the operands to one and you you will get a `float`, so this should do the trick:

```
float StartDay = (NumberOfMonths - FROM_DATE.Day) / (float)NumberOfMonths;
```

Again we have a problem with types with the line:

```
float EndDate = (TO_DATE / EndDay);
```

TO_DATE is a `DateTime` and EndDay is an `int` so you cannot divide them nor could expect the answer to be `float`!

What are you trying to do?